# Does preposition “at” include a part of the object itself?

Tags: prepositions, word-meaning

For example, I’m wounded in the leg, and the wound is a part of me. In this case, can I say there’s wound at my leg? It means purely that there’s wound in/on my leg.

Comment: The only situation I can think of is if you were to say that you had a wound **at the end of** your finger.  But you certainly couldn't say **at my finger**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of a laceration, wound, bite, burn etc. being or appearing "at" a part of the human body. Wounds *generally* appear **on** the surface.

A person can be wounded **at a location** e.g. *1,250 British crew were wounded ***at*** the [Battle of Trafalgar](https://www.thetrafalgarway.org/the-battle-of-trafalgar#:%7E:text=There%20are%20in%20total%20around,detailed%20events%20of%20the%20battle.)*

Comment: Except, as @JavaLatte says, at a location on a body part - _at the side of my face, at the tip of my ear_ etc.